# Making a word search game using C

Tags: c, logic, wordsearch

I have been trying to make a word search game which is of a fixed size of 10 by 10. So far, I have successfully managed to generate the random letters within the word search, as well as the the **4 random hidden words** which are to be found during the game. 
However, I have been having some trouble with how I am going to **fit the 4 generated random words into the word search itself**, whilst taking into consideration that the **hidden words have to be at random positions in every round of the game**. The words have to be **either horizontal, vertical or diagonal**. Also, how am I supposed to generate the 4 words at random positions whilst **ensuring that the words do not overlap one another**?

This is my code so far:

```
char getRandomCharacter();
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char getRandomCharacter(){
    int r = (rand() % 26) + 65;
    return (char)r;
}

int main(void){

    int randomNum;
    char wordSearch[11][11];
    const char *takenWords[4];
    const char *words[20]={"DOG", "CAT", "ELEPHANT", "CROCODILE", "HIPPOPOTAMUS", "TORTOISE", "TIGER", "FISH", "SEAGULL", "SEAL", "MONKEY", "KANGAROO", "ZEBRA", "GIRAFFE", "RABBIT", "HORSE", "PENGUIN", "BEAR", "SQUIRREL", "HAMSTER"};

    printf("\n\tA\t\tB\t\tC\t\tD\t\tE\t\tF\t\tG\t\tH\t\tI\t\tJ\n");
    for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
        printf("\n%d\t", i-1);

        for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            char c=getRandomCharacter();
            wordSearch[i][j]=c;
            printf("%c\t\t", *(&(wordSearch[i][j])));
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        int flag=0;
        do{
            randomNum = (rand()%20);
            takenWords[i]=words[randomNum];
            flag=0;
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                if(strcmp(words[randomNum],takenWords[j])==0)flag=1;
            }
        }while(flag);
        //wordSearch[(rand()%20)+1][(rand()%20)+1];
        printf("%s\n", words[randomNum]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: you pick a random position, you check if anything else is already there. if there is, you pick ANOTHER random position.

Comment: But how can you check that something isn't there? Because there is always going to be a random character even if it isn't the actual hidden word..

Comment: you fill in the random characters AFTER you place your words. start with a blank array, fill in the words, then fill the empty spaces with garbage.

Comment: will it work properly if I write 

if(wordSearch[randomNum][randomNum]==NULL)
?
Because I don't really know how to check if something is already there..

Comment: if you initialize the wordsearch array to nulls, and realize that'd only check one single character slot.

Comment: `memset` the entire array to `-1`, fill in your words, then fill in every remaining `-1`.

Comment: How do you intend to fit "HIPPOPOTAMUS" in a 10 by 10 grid?